# 2 xbox 360s in one house

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

My brother and I both want to be able to play on xbox live at the same time on the same game and different games do I need 2 gold memberships? Is there anything else I need to take into consideration?

Comment: You need 2 separate gold memberships and you're good to go. Something else you might want to take into consideration is your internet speed. I lived in a house with 4 other people and we had to get a faster internet connection because some of us experienced lag issues when we were all playing at once.

Comment: Can anyone clarify if you need two copies of the same game in order for the brothers to play the same game simultaneously? If one installs it to the 360, for example, can the other play it off the disk? It has been a while since I last tried that so I don't remember, but thought it would be a useful add-on for the best answer.

Comment: @Phaelin you need two copies of the game. Installing to the hard drive doesn't let you play without the disk in.

Comment: Note that in some games, like Halo ones, you can play online in the same console with only one Gold account. The other player has to play with a guest profile

Answer (score 9):

Yes, to be able to play online multiplayer at the same time on separate consoles, you will need two separate accounts, each with an Xbox Live Gold membership.